# jQuery: not getting the value of a hidden input

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble getting the value of a hidden input. It seems so simple but I know I must be doing something wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <title>Hidden Field Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            var x = $('#test').val();
            $('#results').append(x);
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="test" type="hidden" runat="server" vaule="false" />
        <div id="results">
            The value is:
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body
```

I also have it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymsc/2/).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vaule` -> `value`

Comment: really, I have been looking at that for like the last 30 minutes. Thank you

Comment: @zk Sometimes fresh view helps :)